# SQLAlchemy - Run method on all query elements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a ***SQLAlchemy*** `db.Model` like this:

```
def Action(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status  = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    def __init__(self, status):
        self.status = status

    def update(self):
        # Code to update status (External query to API)
        ...
        db.sesssion.commit()
```

Now I have a query like:

```
query = db.session.query(Action)
```

I want to execute the `update` method on all elements of this query.

The following is very inefficient because every call to `update` takes 2/3 seconds.

```
for a in query.all():
    a.update()
```

**How can I run `update` on all elements in my query in parallel ?**

Comment: AS far as I know the DB won't do that on it's own. You'll need to implement  multiprocessing (asyncio, multiprocess) or asynchronous task completion (celery) on your own.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand - why would you want to run multiple updates in parallel? Wouldn't a single update work better for you?
I believe your example is missing some details - update with what (where are the values)?
What do you want to do/achieve eventually? Depending on your needs, a different approach may be more suitable.

Comment: The reason I want to run those updates in parallel is because each of those take a long time to run (API call ~ 2 / 3 seconds). In terms of performance it would be way more efficient to do those in parallel.

Comment: I see. Which DB are you using underneath? does it allow (real) parallel updates to the same table? Are you sure a single query performance would still be unacceptable?
If so, then @IanAuld is correct - you need to implement this on your own using application level multiprocessing. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: I'm using sqlite. This is a web UI so yes, performance matters a lot. I think I got a work around using a Celery task to process every action.update() in the background. I will post an answer if I am able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the way I did things, and put a REST API around the `Action` model. Updates are done by sending `PUT` to a `/api/action/{id}` endpoint.

My API client can be asynchronous so that the requests are executed in parallel. Now the REST API itself is multiprocessed and spread over multiple instances and `SQLAlchemy` ensures connections to the database are concurrent.

Client usage looks like this:

```
import MyApiClient
client = MyAPIClient('localhost:5001')
actions = client.get_actions()
ids = [a['id'] for a in actions]
for id in ids:
    client.update_action(id, status='RUNNING', async=True)
```